# .NET Framework 4.8 Developer Pack installation hangs partway through

Tags: .net

I'm trying to install .NET Framework Developer Pack 4.8, but it hangs during installation. The installer gets stuck at this point:

[image]

and never finishes installing. I've left it running for hours with no progress, and it says it's using 0% CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to u/jordanl171 on this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/ipqnqq/net_framework_48_install_stuck_exchange_server/), the answer was to manually start the  Windows Installer service.

First, I had to restart my computer. Then follow the below steps to manually start the Windows Installer service:

- Open a cmd window as administrator (press start, type "cmd", right-click, Run as administrator)
- Type `net start MSIServer`

Then start the .NET install again.

---

I tried just killing the install from task manager, but it seemed to be holding on to some resources and  subsequent installs failed. Restarting the server before starting up the service and retrying the install seemed to work.